# Interpolate values in pandas using the nearest method?

Tags: pandas

How do I interpolate the nearest number?

My pd.Series named df1

```
0      RK
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5     NaN
6       6
7       7
8       8
9     NaN
10     10
```

And I would like to interpolate the nearest number to replace NaN, like this

```
0      RK
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
8       8
9       9
10     10
```

According to Official Doc [pandas.Series.interpolate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)
I tried

```
df1 = df1.interpolate(method='nearest',axis=0)
```

but it doesn't change.

Need help, and thanks in advance. :~)

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure these NaN values are `np.nan`?

Comment: I've tried df1.isnull(), and it return True (NaN). It's np.nan without a  doubt
Thx for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do

```
df1.interpolate()
```

don't bother with the `method='nearest'` option.  The default `method='linear'` should do the trick.